# PowerShell: like operator in setting variable (Subject of email LIKE something)

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I am working with Powershell third hour in my life.

I am downloading attachments from Exchange2010 based on this script: http://gsexdev.blogspot.nl/2010/01/writing-simple-scripted-process-to.html

Right now there are set these variables concerning email set-up:

```
$MailboxName = "email@email.net"
$Sender = "sender@email.com"
```

Later on are these variables used as conditions for action:
IF new email is in "email@email.net" and sender is "sender@email.com" then do some steps.

```
  $folderid = new-object     Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
$InboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
$Sfir = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::IsRead, $false)
$Sfsen = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Sender, $Sender)
```

BTW: does SENDER column in itemschema exist? I didnt find it here:
     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemschema_members(v=exchg.80).aspx

I would like to extend these conditions on Subject of email. This means:
   IF new email is in "email@email.net" and sender is "sender@email.com" **AND subject is LIKE "*&BETA&*"** then do some steps.

I thought I would do st like this:

```
#$Subjecthelp = ".csv"
```

And then I would do :

```
#$Sfsub = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+**LIKE**([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject, $Subject)
```

But it does not really work and I do really know how to write it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
$Sfsub = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject, $Subject)
```

You can find the supported filters in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.searchfilter(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: Looks nice, please dont you also know how to refer to SENDER in email? I have tried: $Sfsen = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Sender, $Sender) but it seems it does not really work

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't know much about Exchange web services -- this just seemed like an easy thing to look up. :)